# Blurring raster data across tile boundaries?

Tags: raster, gdal, tiles, smoothing

I have a raster dataset that is made up of 280 tiles, 51Gb total. I need to smooth/blur the data, retaining the same resolution. I would like to blur *across tile boundaries*, where possible, so that points on the edge of each raster contain information from the neighbouring raster(s). I would like the output to be in the same format or smaller tiles.

I there an easy way to do this? I see that it's possible to [blur using a KernelFilteredSource in VRT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20196/how-to-convert-geotiff-to-grayscale-and-add-gaussian-blur), but it's not clear how that can be made to work across tile boundaries.

I guess the other option is to write a script to load each tile, plus the margins from the surrounding 8 tiles, blur the result, trim, and re-save. I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it before I try that.

Comment: I would have a try in this way: 1) Create a vrt from the tiles with gdalbuildvrt. Let's call the result as mosaic.vrt. 2) Make a new vrt as `gdal_translate -of vrt mosaic.vrt filtered.vrt`. 3) Edit filtered.vrt and turn it into KernelFilteredSource as in the answer that you pointed.

Comment: @user30184 that works incredibly well. Thank you! Please post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write two .VRT files and use them chained:

1. Create a .VRT that mosaics all your source files into one virtual layer with gdalbuiltvrt https://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html
2. Make a new vrt that is referencing this Mosaic as `gdal_translate -of vrt mosaic.vrt filtered.vrt`
3. Edit filtered.vrt and turn it into KernelFilteredSource as in the answer [How to convert GeoTIFF to grayscale and add gaussian blur?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20196/how-to-convert-geotiff-to-grayscale-and-add-gaussian-blur) and as documented in https://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html

Comment: Great, thank you. It's also worth mentioning that any kernel values can be supplied, and there is a nice Gaussian kernel generator available at http://dev.theomader.com/gaussian-kernel-calculator/