# Gaussian in QGIS: SAGA vs Native Tool

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing, raster-calculator

I have been using **SAGA Gaussian Filter** to apply a filter to a raster layer, but for *reasons* I would like to use native QGIS tools if there is an equivalent.

There is a tool called **Fuzzify raster (gaussian membership)** but the cells it creates have numbers between 0 and 1--not a fuzzy version of the source raster layer. Is there a way I could use this tool together with **Raster Calculator** or another QGIS native tool to achieve the same results as the SAGA tool?

Comment: In the raster calculator, if you multiply the **Fuzzify raster** with the original one, it would create a new raster with original values multiplied with values between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20196/how-to-convert-geotiff-to-grayscale-and-add-gaussian-blur. The VRT option allows you to apply Gaussian blur on-the-fly.